# Any way to filter null results in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a XSLT translation that is going over multiple files, and some of the files are not going to have a field. I have a workaround (as seen below) but would rather not have to do that for all of the fields.

*Note: I was using XSLT 1.0, but am now able to use 2.0*

```
<xsl:variable name="TestVar" select="ns2:value"/>
        <xsl:if test="$TestVar != null">
                <Namespace:hasThisValue>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns2:value"/>
                </Namespace:hasThisValue>
                </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to show the exact details of the input samples, in your text you say "some of the files are not going to have a field", in your code you have a check "ns2:value != null" which doesn't make much sense in my view as the right hand side "null" would try to select an element of that name `null`. So as most people asking similar questions you have not explained well what kind of data you expect and which result you want to transform it to, in particular what you consider a "null" value in the context of XML (XSD schema for instance has an `xsi:nil` attribute for that).

In general if you want to transform `ns2:value` elements to `Namespace:hasThisValue` elements then you would write a template

```
<xsl:template match="ns2:value">
  <Namespace:hasThisValue>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Namespace:hasThisValue>
</xsl:template>
```

and simply ensure that further up the hierarchy you have an `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.